# grails 2.5 - can the build scripts be modified?

Tags: grails, gradle

grails has an out of the box way to produce wars.  You just type "grails war" in the project dir.  The question is, is it possible, and recommended, to modify the grails build scripts to do something slightly different, such as to also build a zip of the source which produced that war, and give it the same name?

I know this could be done with external tools such as jenkins running on a build server, but this is out of our budget.

To put it another way, was grails designed to have its war build process modified?

Answer (score 0):

First, the scripts included with Grails aren't meant to be modified, but rather used by your own custom scripts.

Creating your own build process, or Gant scripts not Gradle, is quite easy with `grails create-script` and outlined in the [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.x/guide/commandLine.html#creatingGantScripts). It's not uncommon to see projects which have custom scripts such as `grails publish-build` which creates the WAR, archives sources, sends out notices, etc.

Comment: Excellent.  I have read the documentation, but haven't managed to figure out how to create the war, archive the sources, nor send out notice.  If anyone has an example script or knows of a link to one, I would be very grateful.